# which is the best option for Video streaming? AWS S3 and cloudfront or EFS or EBS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS and I need to know certain things before start coding.

1)For Video streaming am planning to use Nodejs and S3 but the point is, if a video is 1.5GB, the time to fetch the video from s3 to node is very high. So if i use AWS EFS or EBS there wont be any necessity for the API call to S3. is EBS or EFS a reliable way to store huge media files?

2)if i use cloudfront plus s3. the cost is so high as i tried to calculate it in aws pricing calculator
I saw many blog and articles regarding this but they aren't useful to me. can someone who had experience in these, please suggest me whats the best service i can use in low cost also with some efficiency.

Comment: Have you figured out what method/protocol you are going to use for streaming? That will probably influence your choice of storage. If possible, off-load the streaming from your EC2 instances and use the scale of services like S3, CloudFront and AWS Elemental to do the work for you. That way, you won't need to scale EC2 when your usage increases. Frankly, the storage medium is the least-important choice you will need to make. Amazon S3 is the clear obvious choice for storing large objects like video, since it has no storage limits, in-built backups and high bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

EFS is great because it centralizes the data so you can properly scale horizontally, but it has it's downfalls. Specifically that once you get into higher bandwidth usage you will almost certainly need to use static transfer rates to avoid burning through your burst credits.

EBS is nice because you are using the bandwidth of the instance itself, but it doesn't allow you to scale horizontally as easily.

Here's an interesting article I found when i was working on this

[https://www.missioncloud.com/blog/resource-amazon-ebs-vs-efs-vs-s3-picking-the-best-aws-storage-option-for-your-business#:~:text=The%20main%20differences%20between%20EBS,of%20backups%20or%20user%20files](https://www.missioncloud.com/blog/resource-amazon-ebs-vs-efs-vs-s3-picking-the-best-aws-storage-option-for-your-business#:%7E:text=The%20main%20differences%20between%20EBS,of%20backups%20or%20user%20files).